# Self-service VS Entreprise Amadeus API request limits per second

Tags: amadeus

I know that their are some limitations on the Amadeus self service API regarding the TPS (transaction per seconds per user):

- 10 TPS in production
- 5 TPS in test

Do you know if there is this kind of limitation in Entreprise API? I mean if we have hundreds of user using a webapp simultanously, we will quickly exceed this limit.

Actually I have to develop a webapp and I have to choose between self-service and Entreprise API. 
Self-service API are OK four our needs, except the TPS. That's why i'm asking.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. Contact that company's support/sales if you can't find the information on their website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today in Self-Service:

Test: 10 transactions per sec per user (10 TPS/user) -> With the constrains: not more than 1 request every 100ms.

Production: 20 transactions per sec per user (20 TPS/user) -> With the constraint: not more than 1 request every 50ms.

We plan to change that in the future.

Enterprise is a totally different framework. The process to get access to APIs is different and the catalog as well. Please contact us at developers@amadeus.com so we can better understand your need and find the right framework for you.